# Can Dask computational graphs keep intermediate data so re-compute is not necessary?

Tags: dask

I am very impressed with Dask and I am trying to determine if it is the right tool for my problem. I am building a project for interactive data exploration where users can interactively change parameters of a figure. Sometimes these changes requires re-computing the entire pipeline to make the graph (e.g. "show data from a different time interval"), but sometimes not. For instance, "change the smoothing parameter" should not require the system to reload the raw unsmoothed data, because the underlying data is the same, only the processing changes. The system should instead use the existing raw data that has already been loaded. I would like my system to be able to keep around the intermediate data objects and intelligently determine what tasks in the graph need to be re-run based on what parameters of the data visualization have been changed. It looks like the caching system in Dask is close to what I need, but was designed with a bit of a different use-case in mind. I see there is a `persist` method, but I'm not sure if that would work either. Is there an easy way to accomplish this in Dask, or is there another project that would be more appropriate?

Comment: Note that the graph merge tactic i.e. `dask.compute(d.min(), d.max())` will not work in my case because I do not know what manipulations will be performed in the future

Answer (score 2):

> "change the smoothing parameter" should not require the system to reload the raw unsmoothed data

Two options:

1. The builtin `functools.lru_cache` will cache every unique input. The check on memory is with the `maxsize` parameter, which controls how many input/output pairs are stored.
2. Using `persist` in the right places will compute that object as mentioned at https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/manage-computation.html#client-persist. It will not require re-running computation to get the object in later computation; functionally, it's the same as `lru_cache`.

For example, this code will read from disk twice:

```py
>>> import dask.dataframe as dd
>>> df = dd.read_csv(...)
>>> # df = df.persist()  # uncommenting this line → only read from disk once
>>> df[df.x > 0].mean().compute()
24.9
>>> df[df.y > 0].mean().compute()
0.1
```

Uncommented the line will mean this code only reads from disk once because the task graph for the CSV is computed and the value is stored in memory. For your application is sounds like I would use `persist` intelligently: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/best-practices.html#persist-when-you-can

What if two smoothing parameters want to be visualized? In that case, I'd avoid calling `compute` repeatedly: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/best-practices.html#avoid-calling-compute-repeatedly

```py
lower, upper = client.compute(df.x.min(), df.x.max())
```

This will share the task graph for `min` and `max` so unnecessary computation is not performed.

> I would like my system to be able to keep around the intermediate data objects and intelligently determine what tasks in the graph need to be re-run based on what parameters of the data visualization have been changed.

Dask Distributed has a smart caching ability: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/caching.html#automatic-opportunistic-caching. Part of the documentation says

> Another approach is to watch all intermediate computations, and guess which ones might be valuable to keep for the future. Dask has an opportunistic caching mechanism that stores intermediate tasks that show the following characteristics:
>
> 1. Expensive to compute
> 2. Cheap to store
> 3. Frequently used

I think this is what you're looking for; it'll store values depending on those attributes.

Comment: Smart caching looks close, but I don't like the "smart" part. I don't want Dask to decide when to cache tasks. I want to always cache the result of every task and only keep the most recent result of each task. I understand that this is different from the target use-case, but would it be possible to make this happen by changing the settings?

Comment: The builtin functools.lru_cache is what you're looking for. Note: changing the maxsize parameter will change how many unique inputs are cached.